# How to get redux-form FieldArray text field to have readonly with initial values but not when a new field.push is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I need to create a redux-form that loads data into a modal with initial values. One of the fields( quoteField ) should render with readOnly when there is initial data. There will also be at least one quote in the data(initialValue) since that is a requirement. 
But clicking a new quote, fields.push({})} , to add to the form should be free text (not readonly)

I have tried using readOnly={pristine}, readOnly={pristine && initial} etc ... in the component. This works until i add another field; fields.push({})} OR if i click inside another form element. This action causes the quote field (with the initial value) to be editable again. It should stay readOnly.

I gave tried different variations of the meta:objects but none seems to give the functionality i need.
Everything works fine except this issue

```
 // removed imports

    class EditReduxForm extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
      super(props);

 // removed handlers and state 

      }


 // removed function for submitting

      render() {
        const { valueForPRI } = this.state;
        const {fields:{addingName, quoteField}, array: { push }, handleSubmit, addCustom, onNewRequest, form, input, valid, reset, pristine, submitting } = this.props;


        return (
            <span>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                  <Field name="addingName" component={formElement.renderName} value={valueForPRI} >{this.menuItemsPRI(valueForPRI)}</Field>
                  <FieldArray name="quoteField" component={formElement.renderEditQuote} /> // ***** <= this element ******
                {actions} <span className="require"> <span className="ast">*</span> required field</span>
                  <br/>
                </form>
          </span>
        );
      }

    }//end edit class

    EditReduxForm = reduxForm({
      form: 'editForm',
      fields: ['addingName', 'quoteField[]'],
      enableReinitialize: true,
      validate,
    })(EditReduxForm);


    EditReduxForm = connect(
      state => ({
        initialValues: {
          addingName: state.loadFormValues.addingName,
          quoteField : state.loadFormValues.quoteField,
        }
      })
    )(EditReduxForm )

    export default EditReduxForm;
```

and the form fields are pulled in from another file.

```
  // removed imports


        export const renderName = ({ field, input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, pristine}, children, ...custom  }) => (
           <ul>
              <li>
                <Field
                    {...input}
                    component           ={SelectField}
                    onChange            ={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
                    children            ={children}
                    className           ="priorityAutoCompleter"
                    id                  ="addingPriority"
                    errorText           ={touched && error }
                    {...custom}
                />
              </li>
          </ul>
        )


        const renderEditQuote = ({ fields, field, input, value, label, type,  meta: { pure, touched, error, pristine, dirty, initial}, children, ...custom, }) => (
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label htmlFor="quoteField">Quote(s)</label>
                <IconButton
                  tooltipPosition     ="top-right"
                  onTouchTap          ={() => fields.push({})}
                 </IconButton>
            </li>
            {fields.map((quote, index) =>
             <ul className="quoteList" key={index}>
                <IconButton
                  type                ="button"
                  tooltip             ="remove"
                  tooltipPosition     ="top-left"
                  className           ="floatRight marginRight"
                  onTouchTap          ={() => fields.remove(index)}
                </IconButton>
              <li className="quoteListLi">
                <Field
                  {...input}
                  component           ={TextField}
                  id                  ="addingQuote"
                  name                ={`${quote}.addingQuote`}
                  type                ="text"
                  multiLine
                  errorText           ={touched && error }
                  children            ={children}
                  {...custom}
                  readOnly            ={ ????? } // // ***<= this element ***
                />
                <span className="error">{error }</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Field
                  {...input}
                  component           ={TextField}
                  name                ={`${quote}.addingLabel`}
                  id                  ="addingLabel"
                  type                ="text"
                  onKeyDown           ={(event) => {if (keycode(event) === 'enter') { event.preventDefault() }} }
                  errorText           ={touched && error}
                  readOnly            ={ ????? } // // ** <= this element **
                />
                <span className="error">{error }</span>
                <Field
                  {...input}
                  component           ={TextField}
                  name                ={`${quote}.addingSource`}
                  id                  ="addingSource"
                  type                ="text"
                  onKeyDown           ={(event) => {if (keycode(event) === 'enter') {event.preventDefault() }} }
                  errorText           ={touched && error }
                  readOnly            ={ ????? } // *** <= this element **
                />
                <span className="error">{error }</span>
              </li>

              </ul>
            )}
          </ul>
        )
```

Comment: Can remove a lot of the unnecessary code here? CSS, etc

Comment: i removed some code to shortening the post

Comment: How did you solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, you can try to force Redux-Form to do the work for you, but I'd suggest taking over yourself.

Since the logic you describe doesn't need to be related to the overall application state, and just the component state, I'd recommend going down that route.

What I mean - you can pass an `onChange` handler to your `onTouchTap` and disable or enable editing in your field and utilize local component state for this, something like `this.setState({canEdit : true})` when the `onTouchTap` gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement wherein the key field (unlike other fields) has to be written & persisted (to back-end) only once. However it can be edited any number of times between: "array push() API and saving to backend". Once saved into backend it becomes `readOnly/disabled field`. We accomplished it with something like below:

```
const TextCell = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error, visited },
  elStyle,
  writeOnce,
  ...custom
}) =>
  <TextField
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    hintText={label}
    disabled={!visited && writeOnce && !!input.value} // ** This works for us **
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
```

The above component will be initialized as below:

```
<Field
  name={`${rowData}.${fieldName}`}
  component={TextCell}
  label={title}
  writeOnce={true}
/>
```